# Finding the originality of iOS Device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

How to find our iOS Devices like iPhone, iPad, iPod are original or fake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your ios device originality by giving your model number or serial number into this link. The serial number contains 15 alphanumeric characters. It will display in back side of device or you can found by connecting your device in iTunes.

https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do

Comment: What prevents a "fake" iPhone from having a real seriel number?

Comment: You can't get software updates

Comment: But a faker (assuming one exists) could still put a real serial number on the devices, something you won't detect unless you try to upgrade.

Comment: @patrix Not necessarily. It's still extremely difficult to make a fake iPhone, though. Getting iOS to run on something that isn't made by apple is far more work than it's worth. Just ask [@winocm](http://www.twitter.com/winocm) on Twitter (he's been porting the Darwin kernel to other platforms).